# No result when read HBase with Java API

Tags: java, hbase

I'm trying to read rows in a HBase table but the result of my code is always Null (Resultat => ()).

My rowkey is 0_20190826_32897436_162459_1
My columFamily is "Use"
One column is "ABONNE"

```
public static void test() throws IOException {

    // On instancie la configuration
    Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();

    Connection connection = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(conf);
    Table table = connection.getTable(TableName.valueOf("DEV_EDH_SOC_USE:USE_C_CRA"));

    Get get = new Get(Bytes.toBytes("0_20190826_32897436_162459_1"));

    get.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("Use"), Bytes.toBytes("ABONNE"));

    Result result = table.get(get);

    byte[] val = result.getValue(Bytes.toBytes("Use"), Bytes.toBytes("ABONNE"));

    System.out.println("Value: " + Bytes.toString(val));

    table.close();

    connection.close();

}
```

Do you have any idea ?
Thanks.

Comment: It's really strange, in HBase Shell, when I try this => put 'DEV_EDH_SOC_USE:USE_C_CRA', '0000000_1', 'Use:ABONNE', 'test'  
And I try => get 'DEV_EDH_SOC_USE:USE_C_CRA', '0000000_1', {COLUMN => 'Use:ABONNE'}  
It works perfect, I obtain the result  
But when I try :  
get 'DEV_EDH_SOC_USE:USE_C_CRA', '0_20190801_32891820_003627_1', {COLUMN => 'Use:ABONNE'}  
It doesn't work.  
However, my row is in Base :  
0_20190801_32891820_003627_1                        column=Use:ABONNE, timestamp=1578997849814, value=32891820

Comment: What if you try to get this record in Hbase shell without any columns? Like this 
get 'DEV_EDH_SOC_USE:USE_C_CRA', '0_20190801_32891820_003627_1'

Comment: It doesn't work. But when I scan it works. I think ther is some invisible characters behind my rowkey. So the get doesn't match.